# Xcode Basic History Function

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4, uiimageview, xcode4.2

Hi I am new to Xcode development for the iPhone and am stuck on implementing a history function.

In layman's terms I have

4 buttons (each with its own unique image)

(button 1)
(button 2)
(button 3)
(button 4)

and 5 imageviews

(imageview position 1)
(imageview position 2)
(imageview position 3)
(imageview position 4)
(imageview position 5)

Each time a button is clicked (upto 5 times) i need it to be displayed at the appropriate image view.

i.e if button 4 was pressed first it would be displayed at image view 1
if button 3 was pressed second it would be displayed at image view 2  etc.

I would really appreciate some assistance or push in the right direction.

Thanks in advance

---

Update Code:

```
viewcontroller.h

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {


IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview_history_1;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview_history_2;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview_history_3;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview_history_4;
IBOutlet UIImageView *imageview_history_5;

}

// I would think this could be consolidated into one function
-(IBAction)showhistory_1;
-(IBAction)showhistory_2;
-(IBAction)showhistory_3;
-(IBAction)showhistory_4;
-(IBAction)showhistory_5; 

@end



#import ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController



// function to add to history
// Need an if/for statement???
// On button event 1 display result at image view_history 1, 
// On button event 2 display result at image view_history 2.

- (IBAction)showhistory_1 {
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1"];

[imageview_history_1 setImage:img];

}


@end
```

//I'm stuck at creating the function. Thanks again.

Comment: Generally its a good idea to include some code for these sort of questions so we know where you're at and where we to need to take you.

Comment: Hi @RyanPoolos hopefully the updated code helps understand what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks again.

Comment: And Dont use Post title like that because that title is not correct for this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, in your xib, give each button a tag number to easily identify it:
Let's say that you give button1 a tag of 1, button2 is tag 2, etc.

I would then change your UIButton actions to all point to the same function:

.h:

```
- (IBAction)show_history:(UIButton)sender;
```

.m:

```
- (void)setNextHistoryImage:(UIImage *)img {
    if (imageview_history_1.image == nil) {
        imageview_history_1.image = img;
    } else if (imageview_history_2.image == nil) {
        imageview_history_2.image = img;
    }  else if (imageview_history_3.image == nil) {
        imageview_history_3.image = img;
    }  else if (imageview_history_4.image == nil) {
        imageview_history_4.image = img;
    }  else if (imageview_history_5.image == nil) {
        imageview_history_5.image = img;
    }
}

- (IBAction)show_history:(UIButton)sender {
    NSString *imgName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"button%d", sender.tag];
    UIImage *img      = [UIImage imageNamed:imgName];
    [self setNextHistoryImage:img];
}
```

Comment: I receive the following errors Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'UIImageView *__strong' from 'UIImage *__strong'

Comment: Oops, sorry.  Corrected the code to refer to the image property of the image view.  That should take care of it.

Comment: Apologies for late response, yes it did. Appreciate your help. My game has been submitted to app store. I will post a link on here once on there. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
-(IBAction)showhistory_1:(id)sender
{

    if(sender == firstbutton)
    {
       UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button4"];
       [imageview_history_4 setImage:img];
    }
    else if(sender == secondbutton)
    {
       UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button3"];
       [imageview_history_3 setImage:img];
    }
    else if(sender == thirdbutton)
    {
      UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button2"];
      [imageview_history_2 setImage:img];
   }
   else if(sender == fourthbutton)
   {
      UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button1"];
      [imageview_history_1 setImage:img];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do one thing just change the postion of imageview on button click.Use like this and try if its work inform us if not I ll also provide more methods.

```
  ImageView.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, 305, 135);
```

use different-2 position.